# can react-primitives be used in electronjs app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, electron

I read from react-primitives readme https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-primitives#readme, stated that we need to install target platform library to use react-primitives. For windows there is this react-native-windows. If I develop app that uses react-primitives on ElectronJS, is it possible?

I want to develop multi platform app that runs on windows, linux, macOS, android, iOS, and web with one codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Electron is basically a browser. So if you follow the web setup guide for react-primitives it should work perfectly fine.

From the installation follow :

```
web:

npm install --save react-dom react-native-web react-art
```

This also means you can have one config for all your needs.